# Using unary plus (+) to compare Dates for equality

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

The most standard way in javascript way to compare dates that I've seen is

```
let a=new Date();
let b=new Date(a);

let equals = a.getTime()==b.getTime();    //true

/* a==b  is false */
```

but

```
let equals = +a == +b
```

works well, looks quite clear and saves typing.
I haven't seen many examples of that way to compare dates, almost all use getTime().

Is there any drawback or problem with the unary + applied this way?

Comment: It's less immediately clear, I suppose but it does work. The unary plus is, overall, underutilised possibly because of similar clarity concerns. Or simply because people don't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objectively, there's no *pragmatic* problem. The unary `+` triggers the `valueOf` operation on the `Date` (via the abstract ToNumber and ToPrimitive operations), which returns the same value `Date`'s `getTime` does. So you get the same result.

Comment: Subjectively, people may have opinions either way regarding readability, maintainability, etc. But opinions are off-topic for SO. :-)